# CSS Is it possible to center table column?

Tags: css

Suppose I have table with two columns. I can center this table by using:

`margin: auto`

But let's say I want second column to appear in the center. How do I do that?
Is it possible?

Edited:

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|                                                     |
|     ----------------------------------              |
|     |1 column|        2column        |              |
|     |1 column|        2column        |              |
|     |1 column|        2column        |              |
|     |1 column|        2column        |              |
|     |1 column|        2column        |              |
|     ----------------------------------              |
|                                                     |
|                                                     |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Second column is in the center of page/div. If this is impossible with tables how to do it with divs?

Comment: Do you want the 2nd column to be over top of the 1st one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can, although I have to warn you there are several problems with a layout like this. Be sure to understand them before using this.

The HTML required is:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inside">
        <div id="offside">
        </div>
        <div id="center">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are two layers of wrappers here. We using the usual `margin: 0 auto` technique with the outside container to center it, while the inside `div` gets a negative left margin equal to the width of the off-center `div`.

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#container #inside {
    margin-left: -100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container #inside div {
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
}

#container #inside #offside {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

#container #inside #center {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Have a look at it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/DfArr/1/

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. But can you tell me what are possible problems with it?

Comment: @l245c4l: The most obvious problem is that the usable width for your site would be reduced. Working from the standard 960px width, and, say a 200px sidebar, this means that the maximum width your site can be would be 760px. This is not an insignificant reduction, and you'll need to adjust your design along with it. Also, depending on your design, the site may look unbalanced.

Answer (score 4):

Very easy solution...

```
 td:nth-child(2) {text-align:center;}
```

Comment: Centering a column is not the same as centering the text inside it.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to style each `<td>` or `<th>` element with `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible - here's how:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Center second column</title>

<style type="text/css">
.center-second-column table {
    margin: auto;
}
.second-column {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="center-second-column">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>col 1</td>
    <td><div class="second-column">col 2 with some content</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col 1</td>
    <td><div class="second-column">even more content in this col 2</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>col 1</td>
    <td><div class="second-column">col 2</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, you need to wrap the content in your second column in a , as it is not possible to set margin on  elements. On the other hand, you could set the padding-left and padding-right to 25% on all the s in the second column, but that wouldn't give you the opportunity to set background colours and borders on the "cells".

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I want to do is center column not contents of column.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to center the <td> tags themselves? Remember, if you wrap the content in the second column in <div> tags with fixed width, you can center those <div>s and have their content left-aligned.

Comment: Updated the code with something that looks more like your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, No. You can't do that. But there's a work around. Here's how.

First you can adjust the width of the first column so that the 2nd column will push to the center.

Second approach would be to create another column, that makes it 3 columned table. Set the width of the center column to push the last column to the center and remove the center column border to hide it.